# ios phonegap environment not working

Tags: ios, cordova

I have implemented a basic example with phonegap for android in eclipse. Than i went with ios environment. I have downloaded the cordova plugin and created a new project. Then i replaced www folder with the www folder that i have created for android. The index html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html charset="utf-8">
    <title>navigator.network.connection.type Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    // 
   // document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //


    function helloworld() {
                console.log('phone gap log...');
        alert('Hello World'); 

    }


  </script>
  <script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body background="login.png">

  <img alt="" src="login_logo.png" STYLE="position:absolute;LEFT:25px">
    <form STYLE="position:absolute;TOP:175px; LEFT:65px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:50px" >
        Kullanıcı Adı:<br> <input type="text" id="uname" ><br>
        Şifre:<br> <input type="text" id="pword"><br>
    </form>
    <button type="submit"  onclick="helloworld()" STYLE="position:absolute;TOP:295px; LEFT:110px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:50px" >GİRİŞ</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

the style of the screen is same as with android. But when i pressed the submit button, i have got no action or no log in xcode or ios simulator. But it works on android and on eclipse. Why my simple code does not work on ios environment?

Comment: You say the console.log doesn't work - what about the alert() ? Does that fire?

Answer (score -1):

The `onclick` event isn't reliable in the Web View. You need to use `ontouchstart` or another event listener instead. The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) lists the supported touch events.

So in your case you would have to change the `button` to something like this:

```
<button type="submit"  ontouchstart="helloworld()" STYLE="position:absolute;TOP:295px; LEFT:110px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:50px" >GİRİŞ</button>
```

Comment: Click events are triggered in UIWebViews. They're often slower than their touch equivalents though.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize that ``onclick`` sometimes works, because the project I tested in is rather complex... I edited my answer to reflect that.